# PSTricks plotting a strange graph

Tags: pstricks

I'm plotting the graph of a polynomial in `PSTricks` but the output does not look like to the graph of the polynomial... why? My code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pst-all,pstricks,pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\psset{unit=0.8cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-9,-15)(9,2)
\psaxes(0,0)(-9,-15)(9,2)
\psplot[algebraic,plotstyle=curve,linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red]{-8}{8}{1 - 3876218985722260225*x^2/10892114744073986176 + 14975974793271450625*x^4/174273835905183778816 - 317095420958296875*x^6/26811359370028273664 + 194412970920703125*x^8/214490874960226189312 - 2090988251953125*x^10/53622718740056547328 + 99480224609375*x^12/107245437480113094656 - 7879638671875*x^14/697095343620735115264 + 152587890625*x^16/2788381374482940461056}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

and the graph is in the following picture:[image]
Thanks,
José Santos

Comment: (a) please always post a full minimal example which others can copy and test as is. Here there is no document class or preamble. (b) might be an idea to add an image of what you get on your side

Comment: How I can add a pdf?

Comment: Take a screen shot

Answer (score 2):

use optional argument `curvature`, otherwise you get a bezier like curve:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\psset{unit=0.8cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-9,-15)(9,2)
\psaxes(0,0)(-9,-15)(9,2)
\psplot[algebraic,plotstyle=curve,curvature=1 1 0, linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red]{-8}{8}{1 - 
3876218985722260225*x^2/10892114744073986176 + 14975974793271450625*x^4/174273835905183778816 - 
317095420958296875*x^6/26811359370028273664 + 194412970920703125*x^8/214490874960226189312 - 
2090988251953125*x^10/53622718740056547328 + 99480224609375*x^12/107245437480113094656 - 
7879638671875*x^14/697095343620735115264 + 152587890625*x^16/2788381374482940461056}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]